# I'm trying to create an AutoCompleteTextView in my android app. Trouble is, I'm unable to customize it

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

It works well with the following code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fillText);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, typeAutoFill);
        autoTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

//typeAutoFill is my String array that stores the values which must appear.
```

But, the size of the suggested texts are too big for my app. I need to make them smaller. I did look into similar questions posted here..

I tried:

```
android:dropDownHeight=""            //with different values
```

This produces no change.

I also tried following ArrayAdapter with an XML resource file containing only a TextView with the properties of my choice:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fillText);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.auto_fill_item,R.id.autoFillTextView,typeAutoFill);
autoTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this causes my app to crash.

Really stuck with this problem. I've tried various alternatives. Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml, copy it to your project and customize

Comment: Tried that too with no changes. Can you tell me why my XML file won't work in the place of simple_list_item_1.xml. I mean, both contain just simple TextView s.

Comment: did you try different android:textSize ?

Comment: Yes.. that was my first attempt..

Comment: and no matter what **android:textSize** is the text size is the same? it is **impossible**

Comment: No.. you see, the problem is my app crashes when I use my custom design. And with simple_list_item_1.xml, text size is too big

Comment: Sorry, the attribute I tried was, android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" (small, medium, large), not android:textSize. It worked when I gave a hard-coded value with textSize attribute. My bad :( 

and Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set **Textsize=10sp** to your Custom **Textview** or less

Comment: I had been using the textAppearance property.. omitted this simple thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try like this, make the custom design for text textdesign.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textAutoComplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#f45455"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="5dp" />
```

Your Autocomplete

```
AutoCompleteTextView etChoose= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout. textdesign, ChooseList);
autoTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: else try , ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aList); lik this it will show smaller Spinner text

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I did create a Custom Design similar to your suggestion. But using it is causing my application to crash..